# MySQL won't start when starting MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

When I start MAMP on my mac desktop, it won't start up SQL. I've tried several suggestions on the web (kill sql processes, removed files from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56, changed port number for MySQL), none have worked so far.

This is from the error log:

```
70810 11:05:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from 
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56
2017-08-10 11:05:41 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-08-10 11:05:41 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-08-10 11:05:41 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.35) starting as process 35186 ...
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2613466 and 2613466 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2613476 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-08-10 11:05:41 35186 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace hmg/wp_usermeta uses space ID: 2 at filepath: ./hmg/wp_usermeta.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd
2017-08-10 11:05:41 7fffcfae13c0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170810 11:05:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have another installed mysql database version ? Could you provide us the response of this command from your terminal which mysql

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if I do or not.  I only installed sql once.  When I did the commands, I just copied what I got from the web.  I have never worked locally and know a lot about the front end/graphics/css, nothing about the back, so I'm basically stumbling around.  I can provide a response of whatever command if I knew what command is best to use.

Comment: open terminal and type : which mysql. If there is an response provide it to me i will help you to delete it.

Comment: I tried typing ": which mysql" in terminal, it didn't return anything.  Do I need to enter anything before that? I'm a newb when it comes to the command line :(  I tried typing in $mysql first when it didn't return anything.  Probably not doing it right.